# Remove <result> node from SOAP API response in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, soap-api

I need to remove the  node from SOAP API response Magento 2. Below is an example.
From:

```
<env:Body>
    <ns1:customTestAuthV1CallbackResponse>
        <result>
            <resultCode>1</resultCode>
            <resultMessage>response message</resultMessage>
        </result>
    </ns1:customTestAuthV1CallbackResponse>
</env:Body>
```

To

```
<env:Body>
    <ns1:customTestAuthV1CallbackResponse>
        <resultCode>1</resultCode>
        <resultMessage>response message</resultMessage>
    </ns1:customTestAuthV1CallbackResponse>
</env:Body>
```

I have created a module to remove the  node from response but it is throwing an error as seen below

```
<env:Fault>
    <env:Code>
        <env:Value>env:Receiver</env:Value>
    </env:Code>
    <env:Reason>
        <env:Text>SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'result' property</env:Text>
    </env:Reason>
</env:Fault>
```

Does anyone have any idea how can we remove the  node?

Comment: can anyone have the solution?

Comment: when you remove and send the response back it won't accept the response since it require node with name "result" you have to return it